# How do you make node modules available in the Purescript REPL?

Tags: purescript

Is it possible to make all node modules available when running via `pulp repl`? It seems like some only work when invoked via `pulp run`.

I'm following the pattern in the Purescript Book: https://github.com/paf31/purescript-book/blob/master/text/chapter12.md

```
exports.fooImpl = function(onSuccess, onFailure) {
    return function() {
        require('some-lib').doThing(function(error, data) {
            if (error) onFailure(error.code)()
            else onSuccess(data)();
        }

    }
}
```

Purescript definitions:

```
foreign import fooImpl
  :: Fn2 
      (String -> Effect Unit)
      (ErrorCode -> Effect Unit)
      (Effect Unit)

foo:: (Either ErrorCode String -> Effect Unit) -> Effect Unit
foo path k =
  runFn3 readFileImpl
         path
         (k <<< Right)
         (k <<< Left)
```

Now if I hop into a REPL

```
pulp repl
```

and try to call my function, I get an error when I try to call the required library. `.xxx is not a function`

However, if I run via `pulp run` everything runs as expected and the node library function is called without issue.

Similarly, if I run a node repl and call the library directly I similarly experience no problems.

Interestingly, not all node libraries have this issue. Built ins like `fs` work fine, but third party ones are the ones that have trouble in the repl.

Is there a way to make these libraries available when running in the REPL?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a reproducible example? It works for me. I will use https://github.com/nonbili/purescript-msgpack-msgpack as an example. Start `pulp repl` in the repo directory.

```
PSCi, version 0.12.5
Type :? for help

> import Msgpack
> encode' { x: 1 }
"¡x\1"
```

The implementation of `encode'` is

```
-- Msgpack.purs
foreign import encodeToString_ :: Json -> String
encode' :: forall a. EncodeJson a => a -> String
encode' = encodeToString_ <<< encodeJson

// Msgpack.js
var msgpack = require("@msgpack/msgpack");

exports.encodeToString_ = function(json) {
  return uint8ArrayToString(msgpack.encode(json));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was user error caused a name conflict.

### Edit:

I now realize that this is driven purely my the *module* name. As long as that doesn't conflict with the `node_modules` library, all seems well.

Meaning, even if you directly shadow the names on the file system. For instance

```
npm install SomeLibrary
```

```
node_modules/SomeLibrary/
```

And have a purescript directory structure that mirrors the name

```
src/SomeLibrary/SomeLibrary.js
src/SomeLibrary/SomeLibrary.purs
src/main
```

As long as the *module* name inside of the Purs file doesn't match the node_modules library name 1:1, everything will be fine

```
module SomeLibraryPurescript where ...
```

A-OK. Whereas

```
module SomeLibrary where ...
```

fails

<strike>I created a file structure in purescript that shadowed the node_modules name.</strike>

```
src/MyLibrary/MyLibrary.js
src/MyLibrary/MyLibrary.purs
src/Main.purs
```

When purescript populates the `.psci_modules`, it was pulling in my `MyLibrary` module, which seems to have prevented it from finding the *actual* node_modules one.

I fixed this by

1. clearing out the `output/` and `.psci_modules/` directories
2. moving the library I was trying wrap with an FFI into a `Data/` directory
3. `pulp repl`

Resulting directory structure: